# Having trouble getting Dropzone to work with Laravel

Tags: laravel, dropzone.js

Using Laravel Framework 6.18.0

I'm sure this is something simple but i can't seem to figure it out. I don't see the function in the controller being called to actually do the work of moving the file to the server. I've attached a link to the picture below as dropzone seems to be doing its job but the route/controller side seems to be failing.

**My routes:**

```
    Route::get('/uploadpics', 'UploadPicController@index');
    Route::post('/upload','UploadPicController@uploadFiles');
```

**uploadpics.blade.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('js/plugins/dropzone/dist/min/dropzone.min.css')}}">
    <script src="{{asset('js/plugins/dropzone/dropzone.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="content">
    <form method="post" action="{{url('/upload')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="dropzone">
        @csrf
    </form>
</div>

<script>

    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".dropzone",{
        maxFilesize: 3,  // 3 mb
        acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png",
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**My UploadPicController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Coin;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class UploadPicController extends Controller
{

    public function index(){
        return view('pages.uploadpics');
    }

    public function uploadFiles(Request $request){
        dd("i'm in upload");                            //**I never get here...**
        if($request->hasFile('file')) {

            // Upload path
            $destinationPath = 'images/';

            // Create directory if not exists
            if (!file_exists($destinationPath)) {
                mkdir($destinationPath, 0755, true);
            }

            // Get file extension
            $extension = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();

            // Valid extensions
            $validextensions = array("jpeg","jpg","png");

            // Check extension
            if(in_array(strtolower($extension), $validextensions)){

                // Rename file
                $fileName = str_slug(Carbon::now()->toDayDateTimeString()).rand(11111, 99999) .'.' . $extension;

                // Uploading file to given path
                $request->file('file')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can use dropzone on the page with no errors but it does not copy the file to the server-- it's like the function in the controller never gets called (see the dd(); - never hits).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/In8eu.png)

Comment: Check your network tab for a xhr request to `/upload`

Comment: I see a call.  See [l]: https://imgur.com/5LTrrPR <br/>dropzone.min.js:1 XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:8092/upload".
value @ dropzone.min.js:1
value @ dropzone.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ dropzone.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ dropzone.min.js:1
transformFile @ dropzone.min.js:1
o @ dropzone.min.js:1
value @ dropzone.min.js:1
value @ dropzone.min.js:1
value @ dropzone.min.js:1
value @ dropzone.min.js:1
value @ dropzone.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ dropzone.min.js:1
setTimeout (async)
value @ dropzone.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ dropzone.min.js:1
accept @ dropzone.min.js:1

Comment: I'm new to the network tab but i think that the dd("i'm in upload"); must have hit as i'm  seeing it in the XHR console [l]: https://imgur.com/cOuqvnw but not seeing it on the screen.

Comment: So you lead me in the right direction.  thank you.  I'll use the network tab a lot now as it's great. It looks like my issue is that i'm calling deprecated function: str_slug() that is not available in 6.0. They have changed it to Str::slug.   Thank you for the guidance!